# Effective way of pattern matching on multiple Options Scala

Tags: scala

I have below function which returns a flag based on some conditions.

Trying to see if there is a better Scala way to achieve the same?

Basically based on the status of the person there are different rules to be applied finally to derive on the pass_ind flag.

If person status is Student or Unemployment there are some rules on income and if the person status is not in Student or Unemployment there are different rules to be applied on score & income

```
def IncomeScreenStatus(status_cd: Option[String],
                                   score: Option[Int],
                                 income: Option[Double]) : String  = {

 var pass_ind : String = "F"

 if (score.isDefined && income.isDefined && status_cd.isDefined) {

        val score : Int = score.get
        val income : Double = income.get
        val status_cd : String = status_cd.get

        if (status_cd == "STUDENT" || status_cd == "UNEMPLOYMENT") {
          pass_ind = (status_cd, income) match {
            case ("UNEMPLOYMENT", income) if income <= 7000 => "P"
            case ("STUDENT", income) if income <= 18000 => "P"
            case _ => "F"
          }
        }
        else {
          pass_ind = (income, score) match {
            case (income, score) if (score < 100 || score > 150) && income <= 8500 => "P"
            case (income, score) if (score <= 167 && score >= 100) && income <= 10500 => "P"
            case _ => "F"
          }
        }

      }

    pass_ind


}
```

Comment: What about the `else` of `if (score.isDefined && income.isDefined && status_cd.isDefined)` ?

Comment: no else the pass_ind will be "F"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I have few comments about recommended code-style adopted by Scala,

- variable/function/def names are supposed to be `camelCase`

  - `incomeScreenStatus` instead of `IncomeScreenStatus`.
  - `statusCd` instead of `status_cd`
  - `passInd` instead of `pass_ind`

Now,

```
def incomeScreenStatus(statusCd: Option[String],
                       score: Option[Int],
                       income: Option[Double]) : String  = {
  (score, income, statusCd) match {
    case (Some(scoreV), Some(incomeV), Some(statusCdV)) => {
      (statusCdV, incomeV, scoreV) match {
        case ("UNEMPLOYMENT", _, _) if incomeV <= 7000 => "p"
        case ("STUDENT", _, _) if incomeV <= 18000 => "p"
        case _ if (scoreV < 100 || scoreV > 150) && incomeV <= 8500 => "P"
        case _ if (scoreV <= 167 && scoreV >= 100) && incomeV <= 10500 => "P"
        case _ => "F"
      }
    }
    case _ => "F"
  }

}
```

Comment: This code returns "F" when invoked as IncomeScreenStatus(Some("STUDENT"),None,Some(4000)) but the expected output is "P"

Comment: You see this line in your code - `if (score.isDefined && income.isDefined && status_cd.isDefined) {` ? Your code will return `"F"` if any of these 3 options in `None`. Then how is your expected output `"P"` ? You did not specify it anywhere in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this? (I haven't tried it, no guarantess it's correct.)

```
def IncomeScreenStatus( mb_status_cd : Option[String], mb_score : Option[Int], mb_income : Option[Double]) : String  = {

  def nsu( score : Int, income : Double ) = { // neither student nor unemployed
    if ( (score < 100 || score > 150) && income <= 8500 )         "P"
    else if ( (score <= 167 && score >= 100) && income <= 10500 ) "P"
    else                                                          "F"
  }

  ( mb_status_cd, mb_score, mb_income ) match {
    case ( Some( "STUDENT"                  ), Some( score ), Some( income ) ) if ( income <= 18000 ) => "P"
    case ( Some( "UNEMPLOYMENT"             ), Some( score ), Some( income ) ) if ( income <=  7000 ) => "P"
    case ( Some( "STUDENT" | "UNEMPLOYMENT" ), Some( _     ), Some( _      ) )                        => "F"
    case ( Some( _                          ), Some( score ), Some( income ) )                        => nsu( score, income )
    case _                                                                                            => "F"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a first crack at it.

```
def IncomeScreenStatus(status_cd: Option[String]
                      ,score    : Option[Int]
                      ,income   : Option[Double]) : String  = {
  for {
    stat <- status_cd
    scr  <- score
    incm <- income
  } yield stat match {
    case "UNEMPLOYMENT" => if (incm <=  7000) "P" else "F"
    case "STUDENT"      => if (incm <= 18000) "P" else "F"
    case _ => if ((scr <  100 || scr >  150) && incm <=  8500 ||
                  (scr <= 167 && scr >= 100) && incm <= 10500) "P" else "F"
  }
}.getOrElse("F")
```

Creating local variables with the same name as the passed in parameters really confuses the compiler.

Comment: Is None is also handled here ?

Comment: This code returns "F" when invoked as IncomeScreenStatus(Some("UNEMPLOYMENT"),None,Some(4000))  but the expected output is "P"

Comment: @shiv455; Yes `None` is handled here. It is handled to the same effect (but more cleanly and concisely) as the code you posted in your question (after all the syntax errors have been corrected). You say the expected output is `"P"` for this example input but that's not the result your code produces. If any input is `None` then the output if `"F"`. If that's not the correct result then you should fix the code in your question.

Comment: sorry my bad i take back my last comment

Answer (score 0):

In functional programming, it is better to have small functions instead of large one. I would prefer doing something as below:

```
  def screenStudent(income:Double):String = {
    if (income <= 18000) "P" else "F"
  }
  def screenUnemployment(income:Double):String = {
    if (income <= 7000) "P" else "F"
  }
  def screenOthers(income:Double, score:Int):String = {
    (income, score) match {
      case (income, score) if (score < 100 || score > 150) && income <= 8500 => "P"
      case (income, score) if (score <= 167 && score >= 100) && income <= 10500 => "P"
      case _ => "F"
    }
  }
  def incomeScreenStatus(
    status_cd: Option[String],
    score: Option[Int],
    income: Option[Double]
  ) : String  =
  (status_cd , score, income) match {
    case (Some("STUDENT"), Some(_), Some(i)) => screenStudent(i)
    case (Some("UNEMPLOYMENT"), Some(_), Some(i)) => screenUnemployment(i)
    case (Some(_), Some(s), Some(i)) => screenOthers(i, s)
    case _ => "F"
  }
```

Comment: Input `(Some("STUDENT"), None, Some(1800))` returns result different than OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

As your example requires each field to be defined, you can zip the `Option`s together.  I also like to use extractors in place of explicit guards on my case statements.

If your status is a finite set, I would also recommend using a `sealed trait` to represent it.

```
object Example {

  sealed trait Status
  case object Student extends Status
  case object Unemployed extends Status
  case object Other extends Status

  object PoorStudent {
    def unapply(income: Int) = if (income <= 18000) Some(income) else None
  }

  object PoorUnemployed {
    def unapply(income: Int) = if (income <= 7000) Some(income) else None
  }

  object IncomeScoreRange {
    def unapply(score: Int, income: Double) =
      if (((score < 100 || score > 150) && income <= 8500) || (income <= 10500 && (100 to 167 contains score)))
        Some((score, income))
      else
        None
  }

  def compute(status: Option[Status], score: Option[Int], income: Option[Double]): String = {

    (status, score, income).zipped
      .collect {
        case (Student, _, PoorStudent(_))                    => "P"
        case (Unemployed, _, PoorUnemployed(_))              => "P"
        case (Other, IncomeScoreRange(_, _))                 => "P"
      }
      .headOption
      .getOrElse("F")
  }
}
```